# Quantum algorithms speedup illustration

Tags: quantum-computing

I know that to illustrate speed-up advantage of Grover's algorithm we can apply "square root": if the brute force search takes 100 hours, Grover's quantum search algorithm should take about 10 hours. What would be similar numbers for Shor's algorithm for, say, 10-digit numbers?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shor%27s_algorithm, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grover%27s_algorithm

Comment: (Wait - isn't that 360000 seconds, which should shrink to 600?)

Comment: I don't see any estimates for the computing time in the provided Wikipedia reference for Shor's algorithm. Why did you give that link?